# Pull Text file to SQL server 2008 table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, etl

I want to pull fixed field delimited text file to my SQL table (SQL server 2008). Table contains more than 200 columns. While pulling the text file each and every time I cannot split the file, based on column length. 
In SQL server 2000, we have DTS package. Is there any open source ETL software to pull fixed field text file and also to save the package as like DTS package.

Comment: `DTS` was replaced by [`SSIS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx) in later sql server versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2000's [`DTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707786%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) was replaced in later versions of SQL Server by [`SSIS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms141026.aspx).

From the first link (on DTS in Sql Server 2008):

> Data Transformation Services (DTS) has been replaced by SQL Server Integration Services.

You can still [install DTS support on Sql server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143755(v=sql.105).aspx), but I would recommend against it, is it is a deprecated technology:

> Although SQL Server 2000 Data Transformation Services (DTS) is deprecated, you can continue to run DTS packages alongside Integration Services packages on the same computer.

`SSIS` is a more modern tool set, that is supported on the latest versions of sql server (including 2014).
I would highly recommend using the [Microsoft official SSIS tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj720568.aspx) to learn how to use it properly.